# Join not using index and the indexes are exactly the same

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am not sure why this query isn't using an index on the table `world_cities`. The indexes are the same and in the same order. The data types are of the same type and same length. The only difference is the `key_name`.

So why does it not use the key?
if I run the query I get: `318824 rows in set (2 min 51.30 sec)`

Here is what I have done:

```
explain select * from zip_codes zc
inner join world_cities wc on 
    zc.city = wc.city 
    and zc.country = wc.country 
    and zc.region = wc.region;

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys       | key                 | key_len | ref                                                           | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wc    | ALL  | city_country_region | NULL                | NULL    | NULL                                                          | 3173958 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | zc    | ref  | country_region_city | country_region_city | 165     | largedbapi.wc.city,largedbapi.wc.country,largedbapi.wc.region |       1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+


mysql> show indexes from world_cities where Key_name like '%city%';
+--------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| world_cities |          1 | city_country_region |            1 | city        | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| world_cities |          1 | city_country_region |            2 | country     | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| world_cities |          1 | city_country_region |            3 | region      | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+


mysql> show indexes from zip_codes where Key_name like '%city%';
+-----------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| zip_codes |          1 | country_region_city |            1 | city        | A         |      218424 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| zip_codes |          1 | country_region_city |            2 | country     | A         |      218424 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| zip_codes |          1 | country_region_city |            3 | region      | A         |      436849 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your city_country_region key on world_cities has a NULL cardinality, while a non-NULL one is required for it to be use. Running analyze on it should fix it.

```
ANALYZE TABLE world_cities
```

Also have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521673/is-null-cardinality-in-an-index-a-problem-mysql-5-x) for more info on NULL cardinality.

Comment: Thanks! I am running ANALYZE now, we'll see what happens

Comment: It still doesn't use the key

Comment: It should be able to. What is the exact query you're running? Wait, you do know that the join is already using your index, right?